# How to synchronize uniform buffer updates?

Tags: vulkan

I have a number of uniform buffers - one for every framebuffer. I guarantee with the help of fences that the update on cpu is safe, i.e. when I'm `memcpy` I'm sure buffer is not in use. After an update, I'm flushing the memory.

Now, if I understand correctly, I need to make the new data available for the gpu - for this, I need to use barriers. This is how I'm doing it right now:

```
VkBufferMemoryBarrier barrier{};
barrier.sType = VK_STRUCTURE_TYPE_BUFFER_MEMORY_BARRIER;
barrier.pNext = nullptr;
barrier.srcAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT;
barrier.dstAccessMask = VK_ACCESS_UNIFORM_READ_BIT;
barrier.srcQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
barrier.dstQueueFamilyIndex = VK_QUEUE_FAMILY_IGNORED;
barrier.buffer = buffer;
barrier.offset = offset;
barrier.size = size;

vkCmdPipelineBarrier(commandBuffer, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_HOST_BIT, VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TESSELLATION_EVALUATION_SHADER_BIT, 0, 0, nullptr, 1, &barrier, 0, nullptr);
```

Well, actually in my case everything works without the barrier. Do I need it at all?

If I change `barrier.dstAccessMask` and `dstStageMask` to `VK_ACCESS_TRANSFER_READ_BIT` and `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_TRANSFER_BIT` respectively, everything again works fine, layers are not complaining. What is the better choice and why?

If I try to set a barrier after `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`, the layer complains. So I moved all my barriers between `vkBeginCommandBuffer` and `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`. How correct is this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Well, actually in my case everything works without the barrier.

Does the specification say you need it? Then you *need it.*

When dealing with Vulkan, you should not take "everything appears to work" as a sign that you've done everything right.

> What is the better choice and why?

The "better choice" is the *correct* one. The GPU is not doing a transfer operation on this memory; it's reading it as uniform data. Therefore, the operation you specify in the barrier must match this.

Layers aren't complaining because it's more or less impossible for validation layers to know when you've written to a piece of memory. Therefore, they can't tell if you correctly built a barrier to make such writes available to the GPU.

> If I try to set a barrier after `vkCmdBeginRenderPass`, the layer complains.

Barriers inside render passes have to be inside subpasses with self-dependencies. And the barrier itself has to match the subpass self-dependency.

Basically, barriers of the kind you're talking about have to happen before the render pass.

---

That being said, merely calling `vkQueueSubmit` automatically creates a memory barrier between (properly flushed) host writes issued before `vkQueueSubmit` and any usage of those writes from the command buffers in the submit command (and of course, commands in later submit operations).

So you shouldn't need such a barrier, so long as you can ensure that you've finished your writes (and any needed flushing) before the `vkQueueSubmit` that reads from them. And if you can't guarantee that, you probably should have been using a `vkCmdWaitEvents` barrier to prevent trying to read until you had finished writing (and flushing).

Comment: To expand on why this is needed: For what you're doing to work, the data you write needs to be flushed from the CPU cache to main memory before the GPU tries to read it, and the GPU must not still have the old contents of the buffer in its own caches. Most of the time you'll get lucky and both those things will be true, but without the barrier nothing guarantees it. Run the same program on a different computer with different size cache, or faster CPU, or whatever, and you might stop getting lucky.

Comment: Thank you. Is there any way to check the barrier correctness?

Comment: [This page](https://www.khronos.org/registry/vulkan/specs/1.0/man/html/VkAccessFlagBits.html) note says that flushed host writes are automagically available if done before command buffer execution. So in my case explicit buffer is unnecessary. Am I understanding this correctly?

Comment: @nikitablack: That's not what the page says. It says that flushing causes visibility, but that you have to use "synchronization commands" to make those writes *available*.

Comment: @NicolBolas How is _availability_ differs from _visibility_? And the page clearly says: The vkQueueSubmit command automatically guarantees that host writes flushed to `VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT` are made **available** if they were flushed before the command executed. Here I see the term **available**. I confused.

Comment: @nikitablack: Read chapter 6 of the specification. It explains the difference between "availability" and "visibility".

Comment: @NicolBolas I reread your previous answer: "It says that flushing causes _visibility_, but that you have to use "synchronization commands" to make those writes _available_.". Did you make a typo here? Shouldn't it be the other way around: flushing causes _availability_, but I need synchronization commands to make writes _visible_? And how such barrier should look like, do you have an example?

Comment: @nikitablack: No, I got the order right: "then `vkFlushMappedMemoryRanges` must be called in order to guarantee that writes to the memory object from the host are ***made visible*** to the `VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT` access type, where it can be further ***made available*** to the device by synchronization commands." That's a quote from the spec.

Comment: @NicolBolas Then I completely lost. Specification chapter 6 says "The availability operation happens-before the visibility operation". As I understand this means if something is visible - it's already available. Another point is that quote "The `vkQueueSubmit` command automatically guarantees that host writes flushed to `VK_ACCESS_HOST_WRITE_BIT` are made available if they were flushed before the command executed, so in most cases an explicit memory barrier is not needed for this case". Even specification says that barriers are not required. How to understand it?

Comment: @nikitablack: That's describing the behavior of a dependency operation. But the flushing already made the data visible, so the visibility portion of the dependency is irrelevant. "*Even specification says that barriers are not required.*" Please note the conditional you quoted: "if they were flushed before the command executed." Therefore, if that's not the case, then you need the dependency. As I said in my answer.

Comment: @NicolBolas Thank you. I think I got you and I didn't see your updated answer - that's why I couldn't understand you. But regarding barriers I believe I still need one - this spec quote says that after the flushing (that happens before queue submit) data is *available*. But it doesn't say it's visible. Right?

Comment: The key piece of information missing from this back and forth is the fact that a flush makes a host write _available_ to the _host_ domain, where it can further be made _available_ to the _device_ domain, through domain operations (memory barriers), one of which is handily defined by the vkQueueSubmit command.